# TypeError: _send_request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prepare_body'

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

haystack v2.0.0-beta, pyelasticsearch 0.0.6.
When I try to run "python managy rebuid_index" , Error occur:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyelasticsearch-0.0.6-py2.6.egg/pyelasticsearch.py", line 266, in bulk_index
response = self._send_request('POST', path, body, {'op_type':'create'}, prepare_body=False)
```

TypeError: _send_request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prepare_body'

Details in pyelasticsearch.py:

```
#+
    def bulk_index(self, index, doc_type, docs, id_field="id"):
        """
        Indexes a list of documents as efficiently as possible.
        """
        body_bits = []

        if not len(docs):
            raise ElasticSearchError("No documents provided for bulk indexing!")

        for doc in docs:
            action = {"index": {"_index": index, "_type": doc_type}}

            if doc.get(id_field):
                action['index']['_id'] = doc[id_field]

            body_bits.append(self._prep_request(action))
            body_bits.append(self._prep_request(doc))

        path = self._make_path(['_bulk'])
        # Need the trailing newline.
        body = '\n'.join(body_bits) + '\n'
        response = self._send_request('POST', path, body, {'op_type':'create'}, prepare_body=False)
        return response
#+
```

Actually, I added bulk_index by myself, after the error "`self.conn.bulk_index(self.index_name, 'modelresult', prepped_docs, id_field=ID)
AttributeError: 'ElasticSearch' object has no attribute 'bulk_index'`", follow the link https://github.com/toastdriven/pyelasticsearch/blob/master/pyelasticsearch.py#L424-469
Anyone have same experience? Any advices and references would be appreciated.

Comment: You should try accept some of the correct answers to your previous questions - it will encourage people to help you out

Comment: First, that's no `bulk_index`, and I added by myself, there is an extra arguments `prepare_body`. what is wrong with the codes? which edition should I use?

Comment: yearh, you are right ,Timmy O'Mahony.

Comment: I have solved. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963513/attributeerror-elasticsearch-object-has-no-attribute-bulk-index]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963513/attributeerror-elasticsearch-object-has-no-attribute-bulk-index