# AttributeError: 'ElasticSearch' object has no attribute 'bulk_index'"

Tags: django, elasticsearch, search-engine, django-haystack

When I try `python manage.py rebuild_index`, error occur:

```
self.conn.bulk_index(self.index_name, 'modelresult', prepped_docs, id_field=ID)   
AttributeError: 'ElasticSearch' object has no attribute 'bulk_index'
```

I found the link https://github.com/toastdriven/pyelasticsearch/blob/master/pyelasticsearch.py#L424-469 with pyelasticsearch.py, and I dont know which edition it is. Anyway there is `bulk_index` in that code, buy my pyelasticsearch.py is not.
Anyone has the same experience? thanks for ur time.

Plus:
django-haystack 2.0.0.beta, pyelasticsearch 0.0.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django-haystack will NOT work with original pyelasticsearch. You need to use toastdrivens' fork instead: https://github.com/toastdriven/pyelasticsearch
If you use pip, just type:

```
pip uninstall pyelasticsearch
pip install git+git://github.com/toastdriven/pyelasticsearch.git
```

Comment: I have download pyelasticsearch with :`git clone https://github.com/toastdriven/pyelasticsearch.git`. I got `0.0.6`. And now I select the `branch`(I forgot which branch I selected, maybe `master` or `bulk_index`. Any way there is `bulk_index` and argument `prepare_body` in `_send_request`.) I downloaded with zip package. and I found that the edition is `0.0.5`, after installation with `python setup.py install`. And it works.

Comment: Do you mean that I should select the branches? but how do you know which branch should be selected? @jasisz

Comment: OH this ([https://github.com/rhec/pyelasticsearch.git](https://github.com/rhec/pyelasticsearch.git)) is the one I downloaded at the first time, which is the `original` one.

Comment: This is no longer a concern, haystack's own documentation mentions to use pip install pyelasticsearch now.
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html